# Does Captain Picard call Miles O'Brian 'Colm' in Encounter at Farpoint?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I'm not sure if I'm hearing it right, but he appears twice in the episode and seems to be referred to by his real life name. Is this true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Picard refers to O'Brien (Colm Meaney) by his position; [Flight **Con**troller](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Flight_controller)

> **O'BRIEN:** *All forward motion stopped, sir.*
>
> **PICARD:** ***Thank you, Conn.*** Commander, signal the following in all
>   languages and on all frequencies. We surrender. State that we are not
>   asking for any terms or conditions.

In [TNG: Schisms](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/231.txt), The script explicitly states that the left-handed chair on the Bridge is the "*Conn*" position.

Comment: The noun and verb ‘[conn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conn#English)’ isn't related to ‘flight controller’; it's a separate word meaning ‘the duty of directing a ship’ or ‘to direct a ship’.

Comment: @gidds - The etymology is, in point of fact, lost; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/203071/20774

Comment: This is ‘lost’ in the sense of ‘we're fairly sure we have it, but we can't prove it’? Either way, it seems highly unlikely to be related to ‘controller’.

Comment: @gidds - Lost in the sense that the world's finest linguists and lexicographers don't know its origin. Their guess is better than ours, but it's still a guess.