# What's the command that Kirk gives when he turns over command?

Tags: star-trek

Which is correct, A or B? As he turns over the command, Kirk says

> A) 'You have the COM' [as in Command]

or

> B) You have the CONN.' [as in ???]

I've always assumed the former, A, is correct, but a recent television commercial for the new Star Trek app, claims B, which has left me thoroughly confused.

Comment: I don't have a Star Trek specific reference, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conn_(nautical)

Comment: THANK YOU! Now, I understand. 

Comment: Is he turning over _command_?  I think he's only turning over control of the ship and its actions.  He's always the one in command - unless he leaves the ship on some solo venture for a sustained period of time, I think.  (Boinking an alien isn't a long enough period of time: He's still in command, then.)

Comment: “Com” doesn’t even mean “command.” It means communications (as in combadges). I’m surprised by all of the upvotes here.

Comment: @HamSandwich -  That seems a little unfair. There are multiple mentions of officers being "left in command" or "in command" of a vessel.

Comment: Granted, but "com" never means "command," does it?

Comment: @HamSandwich - How is OP supposed to know that?

Comment: Presumably he’s a fan of the show and has watched it.

Comment: @HamSandwich - The US refers to its Central Command structure as CENTCOM, so, yes, "COM" is sometimes "command".

Comment: Dave, “com” never means “command” in Star Trek.

Comment: ....why not turn on captions and find out? ;) It's also said dozens of times in TNG as well. I downvoted because basic research could have determined this (script search, captions, etc...)

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was pretty solid, considering the link to a ST script. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: For what it's worth, in the pilot episode of Star Trek: Strange New Worlds (May 2022), Captain Pike says clearly "You have the com[m]". So now there is "historical" precedence for Kirk using the "wrong" word.

Answer (score 72):

The command is "you have the conn", as can be seen in this [original screenplay from Star Trek: The Motion Picture](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/startrek01.html)

> **KIRK:** Mr. Decker, I'd like to see you in my quarters.
> (toward helm)
> You have **the conn**, Mr. Sulu.

---

The term "conn" is a [naval/nautical expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conn_(nautical));

> One of the most important principles of ship handling is that there be
> no ambiguity as to who is controlling the movements of the ship. One
> person gives orders to the ship's engine, rudder, lines, and ground
> tackle. This person is said to have the "conn."
>
> <sub><sup>— James Alden Barber, 2005, "Introduction", **The Naval Shiphandler's Guide**, p. 8.</sup></sub>

The etymology is lost, but it may have something to do with the *con*duct of the vessel.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely CONN - as in submarine CONNing tower - bridge CONNing stations. Hunt for Red October "Conn, Sonar, Crazy Ivan!" (Communication from sonar station to the Conn) Battlestar Galactica - The Captain's Hand: Garner:"I have to get down there, you have the conn" Adama: "Yes sir, I have the conn"

Comment: The etymology's not entirely lost. The noun comes from the verb (also "conn"), which the Oxford English Dictionary believes most likely comes from the verb "cond". "Cond" itself comes from ["condue"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED8886/track?counter=1&search_id=260492) which in turn is from the French "conduire". Lastly, that French word comes from Latin ["condūcere"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conduco#Latin), which you could trace back further...

Comment: @Laurel - That's certainly one *theory* about the etymology. But when the OED uses words like 'most likely' you know that they're hedging their bets

Comment: Just be careful on pronunciation.  Otherwise, you have Kirk shouting, "You have the KHAN!"

Comment: @Laurel My personal guess, with no knowledge of etymology, would have been that it came from the word "conductor"

Comment: Or control, perhaps?

Comment: That last quote is interesting considering that rule is not really followed on TNG. Sometimes Picard gives maneuvering commands, sometimes Riker.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - The important thing is that they don't give conflicting orders. In the event of a conflict, primacy always goes to the Captain

Comment: @BrianOrtiz It is fairly common, nautically at least, to have an officer junior to the commanding officer doing conns, even while (s)he is present. (S)He will counter any order he deems unwise or unfit, or issue orders deemed necessary and otherwise let whomever has the conn do it.

Answer (score 4):

My memory was 'You have the bridge'. So I checked and

http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/What_does_you_have_the_bridge_mean

gives a good explanation of both the usages

> The conn, likewise is the station one uses to directly control the ship's maneuvers.  The "conning tower" on a submarine, for example, is so named because when a sub is on the surface, it can be commanded and steered from a secondary helm (or "conn") on the top of the conning tower. Both the watch officer (such as the captain) or the helmsman can be said to "have the conn" at any given time. The helmsman has the conn because he is physically manning the station and steering the ship. A watch officer may have the conn because while he doesn't man the station, he directs the helmsman, at the conn, where the ship is to be steered. It is often mistakenly misunderstood to represent the bridge itself, because the same watch officer that is said to "have the conn" is also said to "have the bridge" as he is in charge of the entire bridge watch.

Answer (score 4):

Star Trek attempted to give verisimilitude to the show by basing the ship's culture on naval military structures, officers, and lingo. The proper expression is "you have the CONN."  TNG was consistent in using "CONN" not "COMM." However, Shatner was famous for his mispronunciations of certain words, and he seems to use "COMM" rather than "CONN."   In true seamanship lingo, there is no such statement as "you have the COMM"--the idea that this is short for command is incorrect.

Others have already clearly described what "you have the CONN" means in seamanship, but it is true that Star Trek often seems to use "CONN" to mean command, though at other times it seems to just refer to control of the bridge, referring to the more traditional meaning of the steerage or helmsmanship of the vessel.  If Kirk or Picard is just going to his quarters, the meaning is clearly closer to the traditional one whereas if the captain beams down to a planet, the term "CONN" seems to refer to something more like "command."  Scottie clearly makes command-like decisions when he has the CONN when Kirk is on a planet surface, though he still operates within the Captain's orders.  In any case, fiction can take liberty with these terms in ways actual seaman would never do; but the original expression is CONN, not COMM.

Comment: 'TNG was consistent in using "CONN" not "COMM."' - note that in the 24th century, the term "conn" seems to have drifted a meaning a bit, as from TNG onward, "conn" is the helm station (or its officer). Consequently, Picard customarily says "You have the bridge."

Answer (score 2):

“You have the conn” is borrowed from naval terminology.  It most likely refers to the role of conning officer, who is the officer of the deck (OOD).  This officer is responsible for carrying out the captain’s orders which includes controlling the direction and speed of the ship.  The officer has full responsibility when the captain is off of the bridge.  On naval ships the conn officer will stand watch at 4 hour intervals.  The origination of the term conn and conning is uncertain but could come from conduct (conducting the ship) or from conning line, a rope that connected the wheel to the ship’s rudder.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The top answer already gives the relevant parts of this information, and the rest is really commentary rather than responsive.  When you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments, in the meantime please don't post duplicate answers.