# In the TNG episode "Disaster", could Worf have given an order to a higher ranking officer?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, starfleet-rank

In "Disaster", Worf is put in charge of ten-forward *by Commander Riker*. However, there are higher ranking officers on board (for instance a department head like Dr. Crusher). If one of those officers were to come in, could Worf give them orders? Could that officer supercede Riker and take charge from Worf?

Comment: If it's enough like the US navy then yes; officers in the chain of command  can (and are expected to) command department officers, even if the latter have higher rank.

Comment: @DavidW interesting, I hadn't thought about that. Would it change if the person in charge at the time of the disaster were not in the chain of command? For instance, if the department head of stellar cartography just happened to be there and Riker ordered her to take charge?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky - If Riker gives an order, it sticks unless it's countermanded by Riker or Picard (or Data or Worf, since they're basically trusted to give orders on behalf of Picard and Riker). The key here is to not get hung up on rank, and think more about the chain of command.

Comment: Do you mean "take charge _of_ Worf"?

Comment: @OrangeDog: No, the question is asking if another officer could take charge (of the situation), with Worf handing off responsibility from himself to the other officer.  Taking command (charge / in charge), replacing Worf as the person in command of the situation.  Worf doesn't need a babysitter, or anyone to take care of him personally.

Comment: @PeterCordes they accepted the answer about giving orders to Worf, which is why I asked if that's what they meant

Comment: Does Star Fleet (and the US Navy) have the concept of Line Officers?

Comment: It's called "positional authority"

Comment: The question does not explain what it means to be "in charge" of 10-forward. In charge of what exactly? Security? Emergency response? Running the restaurant?

Comment: @David42 it isn't exactly clear from the show, but my assumption is that Worf was in charge in the sense that he is coordinating the emergency response, and that his decisions on how to do that should be considered final

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are effectively two distinct questions here.

**Can Worf order higher-ranked officers around?**

Worf has been given a direct order by the ship's First Officer; to remain in place and support injured crew coming into the ship's refuge area.

> **RIKER:** *Okay, you and I will try to get there. Mister Worf, this room is going to fill with wounded in a few minutes and they're going to need help. I want you to stay in charge here.*
>
> **WORF:** *Yes, sir.*

He isn't 'in command' of Ten Forward, but as *fourth-in-command* of the ship, he already effectively outranks anyone who isn't Data, Riker or Picard and can give them orders that don't conflict with orders they already have from Data, Riker and Picard.

**Can a higher-ranked officer order Worf around?**

An officer holding a higher *rank* than Worf can order him to do things that don't conflict with his existing orders from Riker, but only a very specific set of circumstances would allow them to supersede an order from the First Officer entirely;

- Receiving a further order from the Captain or First Officer (or Data, since he's higher in command).
- Someone *relaying* orders from the Captain or First Officer.
- Various standing orders and directives from Starfleet.
- Orders from the CMO relating to health matters.

Of course, if Worf's existing orders no longer make sense (for example, if there's a second emergency that requires his assistance or he learns that the current emergency is over) he can be expected to use his own best judgement to act independently, and to then to report to Riker, Data or Picard as soon as convenient.

Comment: Worth noting also that the chain of command pretty much stops at Picard.  If some Starfleet Admiral contacted Worf on a subspace channel or whatnot (or even if said Admiral was on the ship visiting in person but not in command) and gave him contrary orders, he would not be expected to follow them without first confirming with the Captain, since he is ultimately in charge of the vessel.  (Pretty sure almost this exact situation came up in another episode of one of the shows.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - The Enterprise does periodically carry admirals. Given that all Starfleet admirals are moustache-twirling villains, Worf would be well advised to ignore any of their orders

Comment: @Valorum: It seems to me that either of your Answers would be boosted by direct quotes pointing out exactly what Riker says to Worf. Does he say Worf is in charge? If not, then your answer would seem to be correct. But, if he does, then there's at least an argument for the other Answer.

Comment: @trlkly - the other answer doesn't contradict this one.  It supports its.  Trio was the ranking officer on the bridge.  Worf would have trumped Troi if he has been present. Dr Crusher vs Troi would have been a more interesting one and probably based on length of service.  Though from memory Dr Crusher has assumed command before too, so probably would again unless Troi objected *and* pulled rank - assuming her's was greater.

Comment: Worf isn't fourth in command of the Enterprise - he's only a lieutenant (until Generations) and there were several lieutenant commanders above him - including Data, Geordi, Crusher and Troi.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman if you want to get fully technical, assuming Starfleet works like modern US militaries, some random admiral *cannot* actually give Worf legal orders. They can only order Picard to order Worf to do something. This is not, generally, a good game to play, but it provides a lot of clarity and prevents some bad behaviors.

Comment: @HorusKol - At this point in the show (fifth season) Worf is 4th in command of the ship under Picard, Riker and Data. He has a lower rank than others on the ship, but he's the Chief of Security and a bridge officer.

Comment: @fectin - Starfleet is actually modelled on the British naval tradition

Answer (score 44):

There was a similar situation in the episode [The Arsenal Of Freedom.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Arsenal_of_Freedom)

This was a first season episode.  In the first season Geordi was usually on the Bridge, and there was a series of temporary Chief Engineers.

Picard beams down to a planet leaving Geordi in command.

The ship comes under attack. The current Chief Engineer comes to the bridge to take command. Geordi refuses.

Note that the Chief Engineer not only outranks Geordi, he is Geordi's department head, and directly above him in the chain of command.

So there is direct evidence in Star Trek continuity that Worf could have given orders to someone with a higher rank.

> Ship's log, supplemental. Lieutenant La Forge in command. I am unable to beam up the away team due to an unseen assailant attacking the ship. To make matters worse, Chief Engineer Logan is on his way to the Bridge, and he's not paying a courtesy call.
>
> [Bridge]
>
> **LOGAN**: Why are we still in orbit? We're taking a beating.
>
> **LAFORGE**: We've got to hold out as long as we can. Now, if we can disable our attacker, if only for a few seconds, we can drop our shields and beam the away team back aboard.
>
> **LOGAN**: If we follow that plan, we'll lose the Enterprise. In view of the present crisis, I believe you should relinquish command to me.
>
> **LAFORGE**: No.
>
> **LOGAN**: I outrank you.
>
> **LAFORGE**: Mister Logan, I'm in command.
>
> **LOGAN**: The Captain did not anticipate the Enterprise would come under attack. If he had, would he have left the Bridge to you?
>
> [snip]
>
> **LOGAN**: You can't fight this thing and win. We've got to break orbit now.
>
> [snip]
>
> **LOGAN**: Lieutenant La Forge. Geordi. I know you want to do what's best for the Enterprise. So do I. Now the best thing
>
> **LAFORGE**: The best thing, Mister Logan, is for this discussion to end and for you to return to your duties. Now, I'm in charge until relieved by Commander Riker or Captain Picard.
>
> **LOGAN**: You're ignoring my greater rank and experience.
>
> **LAFORGE**: Not at all. In fact, just to opposite. I'm counting on it. Now I need you to get back down to Engineering and get me every available scrap of emergency power you can. The more power we can channel to the shields, the longer we'll be able to hold out. Now, Mister Logan.
> (Logan leaves)

Comment: This is actually quite nice that Logan agrees he can't unilaterally take command, and needs La Forge's consent to do so. Above-average writing.

Comment: This situation is different. Picard has left LaForge ***in command.*** Technically he now outranks everyone that isn't above him in the chain of command.

Comment: @Valorum It's not clear to me what distinction you're trying to draw by characterizing the situation as different from Worf being left "in charge" of Ten Forward. How is it different? Are you claiming that Riker's order does not put Worf in command of the room?

Comment: @Corrodias - There's a huge difference between being told to *stay in a particular vicinity to support an emergency* and *being given command of a vessel*. Worf hasn't been put in command of the room.

Comment: @Corrodias - Thats nitpicking and without an exact quote from the scene to back it up - not really relevant.  If Worf believes Riker put him in charge thats enough for him assume command of TenForward, especially as Worf is command crew himself. If Worf was some random redshirt it might be more debatable - but he's not. valorums answer below hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Minor point - Geordi is a navigation officer in Arsenal of Freedom and wears command red - he is not anywhere within the department of engineering so Logan is not Geordi's department head.

Comment: @Secret squirrel As you say, we need more information. If Riker simply assigned Worf to a post until relieved, than others may be able to relieve him. But LaForge was acting caption. He temporarily outranked everyone else on board. He can only be removed for very serious reasons such as if he is physically or mentally unfit for duty. He can be relieved just because an officer who ordinary outranks him disagrees with his orders or is bored and wants to sit in the captain's chair.

Comment: I thought navigation was part of engineering.

Answer (score 13):

In the real world, you have what Star Trek often alludes to: [the conn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conn_(nautical))

> Within the U.S. Coast Guard, Shipyard and U.S. Navy, the captain of a vessel typically selects a junior officer to perform the role of conning for him or her. Such an individual has the title of "officer of the deck" (abbreviated OOD) or "the conning officer" while on duty, and he or she will stand watches at four-hour intervals carrying out the captain's commands.[1] However, the captain can immediately take the conn by simply issuing an order to the helm.

Turning over the conn is a line [used throughout Star Trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203068/62709).

The idea is that the ship's senior officer can leave a junior officer in command. At that point, the junior officer is acting with the authority of the senior officer. In other words, at some point, it's assumed a senior officer will return and assume command. You wouldn't want the captain coming up to you and asking why you didn't listen to the person who was left in command in their stead.

Rank only matters when there is no clear person in charge. In the same episode *Disaster*, the officer on duty is killed ([transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/205.htm)). The person left in charge of the conn was a Lieutenant. What's interesting is that there was someone more senior than her on the bridge

> RO: We need to start emergency procedures. Who's the duty officer?
> O'BRIEN: Lieutenant Monroe was in command, but she's dead. I believe Counsellor Troi is the senior officer on the deck.
> RO: Counsellor Troi?
> O'BRIEN: She carries the rank of Lieutenant Commander.

Could Troi have given Monroe orders if Monroe were in any other capacity? Certainly. A Lieutenant Commander outranks a mere Lieutenant. But Monroe was in command of the bridge at the time. In fact, we never see Troi's rank factor into TNG prior to this.

Comment: True. Ensign Ro and many TV viewers had a collective "Wait, what?" moment there.

Comment: Just re-watched that scene. Based on her reaction, I think Troi had the same moment. :D

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  There's even a saying in the Army "Don't confuse your rank with my authority."  I had many instances where I was in a position to give orders to those who outranked me, and just as many where I was in the position to take them from people I outranked. It's not uncommon in the slightest.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru FWIW, the writers circle back to that sentiment in the episode [Thine Own Self](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_(episode)), where Troi struggles with the Bridge Officer's Test. She even mentions this event as her inspiration.

Comment: The US Navy (which Star Trek mostly draws from) avoids this by classifying officers as Unristricted Line, Restricted Line, and Limited Duty. Command devolves only to Line officers, which lets you have uniformed doctors without them also needing to be trained to command a ship. Star Trek seems to have done away with this distinction.

Comment: @fectin It may be worth noting that Dr. Crusher made a specific point of being trained to command the ship.  Spock put McCoy in command just long enough to be arrested and McCoy was very baffled.  I suspect the various series focus so exclusively on the bridge crew/cast that the Navy model you described could exist unseen.  For example officers exist in the science departments but they seem to be more like civilian lab managers.